# Remove duplicate lines based on a partial line comparison

Tags: vim

I have a text file that contains thousands of lines of text as below.

```
123 hello world
124 foo bar
125 hello world
```

I would like to test for duplicates by checking a sub-section of the line. For the above it should output:

```
123 hello world
124 foo bar
```

Is there a **vim** command that can do this?

**Update**: I am on a **windows** machine so can't use uniq

Comment: Being on Windows is no excuse for not having nix tools!  [Unx-Utils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) on Sourceforge!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a bash command:

```
sort -k2 input | uniq -s4
```

- `sort -k2` will skip the 1st field when sorting
- `uniq -s4` will skip the leading 4 characters

---

In vim, you can call external command above:

```
:%!sort -k2 % | uniq -s4
```

- the 2nd `%` will expand to current file name.

---

Actually, you can sort in vim with this command:

```
:sort /^\d*\s/
```

- vim will skip the matched numbers when sorting

After sorting, use this command to remove duplicated lines:

```
:%s/\v(^\d*\s(.*)$\n)(^\d*\s\2$\n)+/\1/
```

- To avoid too many backslash escaping, I use `\v` in the pattern to turn on **VERY MAGIC**.
- In a multi-line pattern, `$` will match position right before newline(`\n`). I don't think it's necessary here, though.
- You can craft your own regex.

Comment: your `:sort /^\d*\s/` command doesn't remove the 2nd line that contains "hello world"

Comment: there is now :) Great solution though.

Comment: I guess  -u flag missed in uniq: shold be `uniq -s4 -u`, or better ¸ `uniq -k1 -u ` to skip first field (assuming that number could have more/less than 3 digits)

Comment: This quote from `:help :sort` may help if you are getting inconsistent and nonsensical results when using `:sort` with a pattern: "_When `/{pattern}/` is specified and there is no `[r]` flag the text matched with `{pattern}` is skipped, so that you sort on what comes after the match._"

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '!a[$2$3]++' file
123 hello world
124 foo bar
```

First element when enters the array sets the count as 1, and hence the further occurrences does not enter into the array since the negation makes it false.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about in vim, but you could do something with the uniq command.  It has a --skip-fields argument that can be used to skip the first part of each line.

```
$ cat test.txt
123 hello world
124 foo bar
125 hello world

$ cat test.txt | sort -k 2 | uniq --skip-fields=1 | sort
123 hello world
124 foo bar
```

Answer (score -1):

In VIM I was able to sort and remove duplicates with the following command

```
:sort u
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. This is for full line duplicates. The OP wants to remove dups based on partial match.